# URL/form params passed automatically to action via Html.Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

We have a layout view in a single-page (Ajax-based) MVC app, that can receive a pair of parameters as URL parameters or form data (to the `Home.Index` action). The `Home.Index` controller and layout view do nothing with the two parameters, but the layout view calls `Html.Action("Index", "Search")` to render a partial view that expects those two parameters.

It works, but how do the parameter values actually pass to `Search.Index` from `Home.Index`?

I would have expected that `Home.Index` would have to put the parameter values in its view data, and the view's call to `Html.Action` to pass them on to `Search.Index` in e.g. an anonymous object argument:

`Html.Action("Index", "Search", new { arg1 = model.arg1, arg2 = model.arg2 })`

Apparently, this is not required. So how does it work?

Note: the app was written with MVC 3 but has just been upgraded to MVC 5, where it still works.

Comment: u are asking how do the paramters get passed in Search acton method when u didn't pass it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm satisfied that it works, but I'd like to understand WHY it works.

Comment: No default parameters given in action are you sure?? If yes ,then check in Route.config for that action method.Or check jquery Ajax method for that.There might be multiple calls to that action method. Better if you provide some code here